# Pylint is not suggesting the walrus operator. Why?

Tags: python, pylint, python-assignment-expression

I was going to ask if there is a pylint-style code analyzer capable of suggesting the use of the `:=` operator in places were it might improve the code. However, it looks like such test has been added to the `pylint` two years ago -> [github PR (merged)](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/pull/4876).

Anyway I never saw such suggestion, not even for this example like in the linked PR:

```
x = 2
if x:
    print(x)

# -----
# if (x := 2):
#    print(x)
# -----
```

This feature is available since Python 3.8. (I'm using recent Python and pylint versions.) I though I have to enable it somehow, but the help says:

> **--py-version <py_version>**
> Minimum Python version to use for version dependent checks. Will
> default to the version used to run pylint.

What is wrong? Why there is no `consider-using-assignment-expr` from `pylint`?

Comment: You're not going to find this, because it does not improve the code.  Your first example is better programming.  The walrus operator was added late because it is controversial.

Comment: It isn't enabled by default (moved to extension and disabled in [this PR](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/pull/7628)). And I'd say that usually this change is not what you want: walrus is handy mostly in `elif` branches (to avoid nesting and extensive computations) or `while` (when it's used like `for` but on something that is not iterable).

Comment: To those who VTC: this question is not opinion-based at all. It asks a very self-contained question about `pylint` behavior (namely - why doesn't the linter fail a rule check on given code), which can be answered as is based on facts and code history.

Comment: @STerliakov: That change was for augmented assignments (like `+=`), not assignment expressions. Much as I dislike it, `consider-using-assignment-expr` is enabled by default in the codestyle extension, as long as you enable the extension itself.

Comment: `consider-using-augmented-assignment` is disabled by default even if you enable the extension. Strangely, this appears to have nothing to do with the fact that changing `a = a+b` to `a += b` can change the meaning of the line. Nobody brought that fact up in any of the discussion I can see surrounding the change.

Comment: @user2357112 augh, sorry, thank you. I failed to check code in the issue title against my search. It's still a `CodeStyle` plugin member, but was there from the very beginning (as mentioned in PR linked by the OP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `consider-using-assignment-expr` check in `pylint` can be enabled by Adding the following line to your pylint configuration file. I am using a configuration file named `pylint.toml`:

```
[tool.pylint.main]
load-plugins="pylint.extensions.code_style"
```

Then you can run the linter using `pylint --rcfile <config_file> <python_file>`.

See [here for more instructions](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/refactor/consider-using-assignment-expr.html). Note that I am using Python 3.11, and Pylint 2.17, but the check should be available since Python 3.8.